# ProgressBar runs too fast than defined

Tags: c#, winforms

my application runs files and every file has it's own running time.
this function get in millisecond the time that the progress time should run:

```
timerProgress = my timer
pbStatus = my progress bar

public void AnimateProgBar(int milliSeconds)
{
    if (!timerProgress.Enabled && milliSeconds != 0)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = 0;;
        timerProgress.Interval = milliSeconds / 100;
        timerProgress.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

and this is my timer that fill the progress bar:

```
   private void timerProgress_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pbStatus.Value < 100)
        {
            pbStatus.Value += 1;
            pbStatus.Refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            timerProgress.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

my problem is that progress bar runs too fast for example if AnimateProgBar get the value of 12000 (12 seconds) the progress bar runs only for 6-7 seconds.

Comment: You devide (`milliSeconds / 100`) the total miliseconds. That is why it runs faster than you want.

Comment: I assume the Min and Max values of your progress bar are 0 and 100 and that the step = 1?

Comment: yes, min = 0, max = 100 and step = 1, how to fix it ?

Comment: On my PC (Windows 8) I run your code with the specified interval 12000 and it works perfectly, it takes exactly 12 seconds. If I try with a shorter duration such as 5000 it takes about 6.6 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's fishy that your code doesn't work. I tried it a few times, and it missed with about 0.6 seconds each time; it seems like ***the timer is just imprecise***.

What you could do is to take care of the time yourself instead of trusting a timer:

```
WithEvents Tmr As New Timer With {.Interval = 100}
Dim startTime As Date, AnimationTime%

Sub AnimateProgress(ms%)
    If ms <= 0 Then Exit Sub

    ProgressBar1.Value = 0
    AnimationTime = ms
    startTime = Now

    Tmr.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Tmr_Tick() Handles Tmr.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Value = Math.Min((Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds / AnimationTime, 1) * 100
    If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then Tmr.Stop()
End Sub
```

---

**EDIT - Response to the reply bellow:**

Oh sorry, no it's vb.net. I know both the languages just as well, but I prefer vb, and tend to think that everypony else does so too.

Here's the c# version:

```
DateTime startTime; int animationTime;

void AnimateProgress(int ms) {
    if (ms <= 0) return;

    progressBar1.Value = 0;
    animationTime = ms;
    startTime = DateTime.Now;

    Tmr.Start();
}

private void Tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    progressBar1.Value = (int)(Math.Min((DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds / animationTime, 1) * 100);
    if (progressBar1.Value == 100) Tmr.Stop();
}
```

Comment: @user2214609 He's updated the thread. Don't be rude... He made an effort to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this sample, based on `PerformStep method`

```
var progressBar = new System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar();
progressBar.Maximum = 100;
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Step = 10;

//begin loop

//Your treatment of step 
progressBar.PerformStep();

//end loop
```

msdn link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep(v=vs.80).aspx

You have sample here

```
private void CopyWithProgress(string[] filenames)
{
    // Display the ProgressBar control.
    pBar1.Visible = true;
    // Set Minimum to 1 to represent the first file being copied.
    pBar1.Minimum = 1;
    // Set Maximum to the total number of files to copy.
    pBar1.Maximum = filenames.Length;
    // Set the initial value of the ProgressBar.
    pBar1.Value = 1;
    // Set the Step property to a value of 1 to represent each file being copied.
    pBar1.Step = 1;

    // Loop through all files to copy.
    for (int x = 1; x <= filenames.Length; x++)
    {
        // Copy the file and increment the ProgressBar if successful.
        if(CopyFile(filenames[x-1]) == true)
        {
            // Perform the increment on the ProgressBar.
            pBar1.PerformStep();
        }
    }
}
```

link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar.performstep(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: foreach terminated step add rogressBar.PerformStep(); , the first four lines , you set in the top of your method for initialize your behavior

Comment: all this code inside my AnimateProgBar method ? what about my timer ? and what loop you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your issue. I just tested a new form, with a ProgressBar and a Timer as you detailed in your question, and merely added one button to start the test, and one label to show the elapsed time:

```
    DateTime start;
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        start = DateTime.Now;
        AnimateProgBar(12000);
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalSeconds.ToString();
        //the rest of your code, starting with "if (pbStatus.Value < 100)"
```

I consistently got 12.6 seconds until the progressBar filled (and the timer stopped, freezing the label text)... Maybe part of your progressBar is hidden?

[Edit]
If you're curious about the 0.6 extra seconds that BlackCap also noticed, it's because you're setting the timer interval to 120 milliseconds, but timer events have a resolution of about 18 milliseconds, so it will actually fire at 126 instead of 120.